# Returning the contents of an arbitrary array

Tags: multidimensional-array, common-lisp

There are many Common Lisp functions to access the various properties of an arbitrary array, for example `array-dimensions`. But a function that returns a copy of the contents of the array (in the same format used to enter `:initial-contents` in `make-array`) is not provided. `Loop ... collect` would seem useful, but the dimensional nesting is arbitrarily deep. Would a macro be appropriate, or is there a better way?

Comment: Macros are code transformation tools. You need a function here, not a macro. However, it is unclear why you would want such a function. Could you please add motivation?

Comment: See https://github.com/Publitechs/cl-utilities/blob/master/copy-array.lisp

Comment: @sds My general impression(?) is that the sequence functions are more powerful & flexible than basic array element manipulation, so array conversion to nested sequences may offer some advantages. For example, given a 4x4 square array of integers 1..16 represented as nested lists might be easily reduced by `(mapcar (lambda (row) (remove-if #'evenp row)) list-array)` to a 4x2 nested list-array of odd integers. But I'm not familiar with `adjust-array` yet, which may offer similar functionality.

Comment: @coredump Yes, I'm wondering if `copy-array` could be modified to return nested lists simply based on the value of `array-dimensions`. No need to copy properties either...

Comment: @davypough: your general impression is wrong. Check out [`row-major-aref`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_row_ma.htm) and [`array-row-major-index`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ar_row.htm). Arrays are a different data type which has its own place and use case. You should use the type appropriate for the problem.

Comment: @sds My point was simply that the array functions operate on array elements one at a time, while the sequence functions operate on a whole sequence (multiple elements) at once. And I completely agree with your comment about using the appropriate type. That's why it may be useful to convert between different types. If you happen to have an existing (library) algorithm that accepts a given data type, then all you need to do is convert your data to that type. Alternately, changing a problem's data representation often leads to a simpler or more efficient algorithm, if you are writing your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros is a code-generation/language-extension tool.
You do not need them here.

What you need is a recursive function:

```
(defun array-to-nested-sequences (array &rest indexes)
  "Extract the section of the multidimentional array defined by the indexes.
Must be (<= (length indexes) (array-rank array)) ==> T.
When (= (length indexes) (array-rank array)), this is equivanent to AREF."
  (let ((ni (length indexes)))
    (if (= ni (array-rank array))
        (apply #'aref array indexes)
        (loop for i from 0 below (array-dimension array ni)
          collect (apply #'array-to-nested-sequences array
                         (append indexes (list i)))))))

(setq init '(((1 2 3 4) (5 6 7 8) (9 10 11 12))
             ((13 15 15 16) (17 18 19 20) (21 22 23 24)))
      array (make-array '(2 3 4) :initial-contents init))

(equal (array-to-nested-sequences array)
       init)
==> T
(equal (array-to-nested-sequences array 1) (second init))
==> T
```

`array-to-nested-sequences` can actually extract sub-arrays.

Note that the depth of recursion is the rank of the array, so you are unlikely to run out of stack.

Comment: `(elegance-incarnate 'sds) -> T` It also works for vectors, disregarding fill-pointer. You may be amused to know my temporary solution was `(read-from-string (subseq (format nil "~S" array) 3))` (until coredump set me straight)!